# java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection cannot be cast to com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.Connection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to develop a Java EE application that connect to an Oracle database.
I am using ojdbc6 jar. I am reading the database info from property file.

```
package com.varun.util;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.Connection;

public class DbUtil {

    private static Connection connection = null;
    public static Connection getConnection(){
        if(connection!=null)
        {
            return connection;
        }
        else
        {
            try{

                Properties prop=new Properties();
                InputStream inputStream=DbUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/db.properties");
                prop.load(inputStream);
                String driver =  prop.getProperty("driver");
                String url = prop.getProperty("url");
                String user = prop.getProperty("user");
                String password = prop.getProperty("password");
                Class.forName(driver);
                connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

            }catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return connection;
        }
    }

}
```

I am getting an exception saying:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection cannot
>   be cast to com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.Connection

I am not getting the root cause. I have changed the jar file as well, but still it is throwing the same error.

Comment: Can you post the imports part of your code? please check your imports if you are importing `import com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.Connection;` ??

Comment: In fact the `oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection` is of type `java.sql.Connection` so you must use `import java.sql.Connection` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your import, check if you have this import in your code:

```
import com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.Connection;
```

It should be :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
```

Take a look at [**This tutorial**](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-db-via-jdbc-driver-java/).

Comment: When I am importing import oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection; I am getting an error: The type oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection is not visible.

Comment: You don't have the relevant jar in your classpath.

Comment: I have downloaded the ojdbc14 from oracle site. Though I am getting the same error

Comment: How can I see the content of jar that it contains "oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection"

Comment: @varun: You have downloaded the jar, but is it on your classpath?

Comment: @CodeNewbie yes , " import oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection " not visible but when I imported this " import java.sql.Connection " error is gone and the connection is getting created. could you please tell me the difference or still I need to download the proper jar

Comment: @varun no you don't need to download this jar in fact the `oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection` is of type `java.sql.Connection` so you must use `import java.sql.Connection` .

Answer (score 2):

try to change the import from

```
import com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.Connection;
```

to

```
import java.sql.Connection;
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix your import for `Connection`. It must not be `com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.Connection`.

Comment: When I am importing import oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection; I am getting an error: The type oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection is not visible.

Answer (score 1):

`DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)` returns an instance of 'oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection', and you are attempting to cast it to 'com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.Connection'. This is the cause for your error.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your import.

> use java.sql.Connection.

Problem get solved.